# How to apply a function to all rows of a dataframe using another dataframe as an input of that function in r

Tags: r, apply

I know my question might look vague but I could not find a better explanation for that. I had been dealing with this problem for a while and I ended up using for loop on all rows to avoid this problem but I am sure there is a solution for my concern. I have data frame A including three columns. I need to check the data in one of the columns for all rows and replace it with other values if they meet a condition (for example if they are NA, I want to replace them with a value from dataframe B which is a match of this row in one feature). Assume dataframe A includes zipcode, lat and long as follows:

```
    zip     lat    long
    44121   41.5   -81.6
    60618   NA     NA
     ...
```

dataframe B is a database of all us zip codes and their corresponding lat and long. I want to check all rows of dataframe A and if there is an NA in the lat column, It find the corresponding lat from dataframe B based on column zip which is mutual between the two dataframe. I wrote this code but keep getting an error for that:

```
    A$lat <- ifelse(is.na(A$lat),B[B$zip==A$zip,"lat"],A$lat)
```

the error is :

```
    longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

I appreciate any help. I know might be an easy question but I could not fix it for a while.

Comment: Have a look at `plyr::mapvalues`. I found this to be quite handy when I have to deal with exactly the same type of data.

Comment: @Tino thank you for your suggestion. I will take a look at it

Comment: You can also tweak your code with `match` function:
    `A$lat <- ifelse(is.na(A$lat),B[match(A$zip,B$zip),"lat"],A$lat)`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with your code is that `B$zip==A$zip` could return multiple true values. there is nothing in the statement to specify that you are only comparing `A$zip` at the row where `is.na(A$lat)`.

Here, I think I've done what you want using the `dplyr` package. If table B has all of the zip codes that you want, then I'm not sure why you want the zip codes from table A. Maybe table A has more precision than table B. In any case, this seems to work:

```
library(dplyr)

dfA <- tribble(
~zip,     ~lat,    ~long,
44121 ,  41.5,   -81.6,
60618,   NA,     NA,
38112,  NA,      NA,
29656,  33,       -81)


dfB <- tribble(
  ~zip, ~lat, ~long,
  11111,40,   -80,
  22222, 50,  -70,
  60618, 32,   -78,
  38112, 32,   -83 )

## If you want to keep the lat-longs in dfA and only replace NAs
dfC <- left_join( dfA, dfB, by="zip") %>%
  mutate(lat=if_else(is.na(lat.x), lat.y, lat.x),
              long=if_else(is.na(lat.x), lat.y, lat.x)) %>%
  select(-lat.x, -lat.y, -long.x, -long.y)

## If dfB has all of the lat-longs you need:
dfD <- select(dfA, -lat, -long) %>%
         left_join(dfB)
```

Comment: I agree with your comment about why my code is not working. About the point why I am using dataframe A and B, Dataframe A has multiple other columns. To fill missing values for those specific columns, I use dataframe B which is a source for all US zipcodes to fill the missing columns.

Comment: ok, I've modified the code so that it doesn't drop any of the other columns dfA has. If dfB has all of the lat-long information you need, then it is a simple left_join . If dfA has some lat-long information that isn't in dfB, and you really only want to replace the missing values, then I've provided an option for that as well.